# What is LeastMaxValue in std::counting_semaphore<LeastMaxValue>?

Tags: c++, multithreading, semaphore

Is it the max allowed value of the inner `counter`? But how is it possible to talk about minimum max value? Shouldn't `max` value be const? How can it be changed? What is difference between `LeastMaxValue` and `counter`?

> As its name indicates, the LeastMaxValue is the minimum max value, not
> the actual max value. Thus max() can yield a number larger than
> LeastMaxValue.
> https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore/max

> The constructor call `std::counting_semaphore<10> sem(5)` creates a
> semaphore sem with an at least maximal value of 10 and a counter of 5.
> https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/semaphores-in-c-20

Comment: it doesnt need to be modifiable. If `LeastMaxValue` is `5` then the actual max value can be eg `10`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number LeastMaxValue is value of what? Is it an amount of thread or value of counter?

Comment: its a lower bound for the max value. Its the least max value. Not sure if this is just a language barrier. You ask for some amount (least max value) and what you get is at least that or more (the actual max)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number it is said :"counting_semaphore allows more than one concurrent access to the same resource, for at least LeastMaxValue concurrent accessors" which might mean that it is about the amount of threads https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't max value be const?

Yes. In fact, [`counting_semaphore<LeastMaxValue>::max()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore/max) is required to be `constexpr`, meaning that it is not just constant, but a compile-time constant. For a given `LeastMaxValue`, the `max` can vary from compilation to compilation, but no more than that.

Perhaps that's the source of your confusion? From the perspective of watching a program run, the `max()` corresponding to a given `LeastMaxValue` is constant. From the perspective of making sure code works across multiple compilers and platforms, `max()` can vary.

---

When you declare a variable whose type is `std::counting_semaphore<5>`, you are declaring that the variable's counter will need to go up to `5`. This becomes a request to the compiler that the counter be able to hold `5`. If it happens that the counter can hold `255`, well that's fine. You don't plan to raise the counter that high, so your code will function correctly with that maximum.

Look at the [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore/counting_semaphore) of `std::counting_semaphore<LeastMaxValue>`. This will function correctly as long as the initial value of the counter satisfies `0 <= initial` and `initial <= max()`. The first condition is easy to satisfy, but how do you satisfy the second? You can do this by satisfying a more stringent requirement – make sure `initial <= LeastMaxValue`. This is more stringent, because the compiler is obligated to ensure that for your choice of `LeastMaxValue`, the corresponding `max()` is at least as large; that is, `LeastMaxValue <= max()`. As long as you specify a high enough value for `LeastMaxValue`, the constructor will work as intended with your initial value.

There is a similar requirement for [`release()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore/release) to function correctly. Correct behavior requires that the counter not exceed `max()`, which you can ensure by not exceeding `LeastMaxValue`. You do get correct behavior if the counter ends up between `LeastMaxValue` and `max()`, but then you are subject to the whims of your compiler. A different compiler might give you a lower `max()`. If you want to play in this area, your code needs to adapt to a `max()` that can change from compiler version to compiler version.

You could think of this as being similar to `int_fast8_t` in that the `8` specifies the minimum size of the type, but the compiler can give you more. You are guaranteed that the maximum value that can be stored in this type is at least `127` (the minimum max value). You might get more than 8 bits in this type, and hence be able to store higher values, but you might not.

Comment: I need more clarity please. So as I see, `max` shows counter's maximum possible value, which completely depends on compiler etc. Ok, but we need smth. we can affect on. Hence we use `LeastMaxValue` instead of `max` . And by `LeastMaxValue` we are declaring our intention to work with such a values of counter, and if `LeastMaxValue` is more than `max` compiler will notify by error or warning. Whereas if I didn't specify `<LeastMaxValue>` I could have troubles in runtime when it got obvious that we want `counter` to have a value exceeding `max` for example. Is it correct conclusion?

Comment: @MaxPopov *"if `LeastMaxValue` is more than `max`"* -- this is not allowed to happen. As I wrote, the compiler is obligated to ensure `LeastMaxValue <= max()`. Perhaps this has too  many details omitted? The compiler is obligated to ensure `LeastMaxValue <= std::counting_semaphore<LeastMaxValue>::max()`. Hmm... maybe I should reverse that inequality to be `max >= LeastMaxValue` since `max` is what the compiler controls. You choose `LeastMaxValue` then the compiler picks the `max`.