# std::counting_semaphore: for what is used template param?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20, semaphore

Just in education proposes I've tried to use `std::counting_semaphore` from C++20 and immediately faced a question/an issue.

According to CPP Reference [`std::counting_semaphore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore) has two parametrs in it's set up:

1. `LeastMaxValue`(in template)- is the minimum max value, not the actual max value
2. `desired`(in constructor) - the value to initialize counting_semaphore's counter with

Using GCC 12.2.1, it's possible to write something like:

```cpp
std::counting_semaphore<0> sem(10);
```

And semaphore will let in up to 10 threads. The template value is just ignored...

And if we go to `libstdc++-v3/include/std/semaphore`, we will found that `__least_max_value` is used only in the `max()` method.

So, what is the purpose of the template parametr? For what it can be used?

I see only such case

```cpp
using semaphore_t = std::counting_semaphore<5>;
semaphore_t sem(semaphore_t::max());
```

Thank you so much for help!

UPD:
So,based on community answers we can say that `LeastMaxValue`(template parameter) designed to be an upper bound for `desired`(argument in constructor). And it's working as expected in Microsoft compiler (see [that check](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/2f03bdf361f7f153b4216c60a0d9491c0be13a73/stl/inc/semaphore#L67)). But for some reason we don't have such check in GCC (see [semaphore class in GCC](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/semaphore#L46)). I'm looking for answer, why GCC just abandon such check.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70468595/17017616) answer your question?

Comment: `static_assert(__least_max_value <= __semaphore_impl::_S_max);` My only idea is that it is used to statically check the required maximum platform supported semaphore count. So I have a program that uses 2^33 threads and I want to use `std::counting_semaphore sem(pow2(33))`. I can do  `std::counting_semaphore<pow2(33)>` and compiler will not compile if the platform does not support that many threads.

Answer (score 2):

The first reason is that the semaphore can be specialized for smaller numbers to be more efficient. This is usually done with `std::counting_semaphore<1>`/`std::binary_semaphore`.

The second is that if `LeastMaxValue` exceeds some implementation-defined limit (e.g., for a POSIX semaphore, `SEM_VALUE_MAX`), the compiler can warn you. For example, on my system `SEM_VALUE_MAX` happens to be `INT_MAX`, and `std::counting_semaphore<SEM_VALUE_MAX+1ll>` doesn't compile.

`std::counting_semaphore<0> sem(10);` can be undefined behaviour. Your standard library could specialize `std::counting_semaphore<0>` to be very efficient by having no state (so `std::counting_semaphore<0>::max() == 0`), so asking for a count of 10 just wouldn't work.

Comment: So, [cppreference's constructor documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore/counting_semaphore) is wrong, because it does not mention the undefined behavior?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It's under the preconditions on that page `desired <= max()`. `max() >= LeastMaxValue`, so `max()` could equal `0`. It wouldn't work in microsoft's STL for example: <https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/2f03bdf361f7f153b4216c60a0d9491c0be13a73/stl/inc/semaphore#L67>. libstdc++ seems to have `max()` return `SEM_VALUE_MAX`, so it wouldn't be UB there.

Comment: No, `max` is a static `constexpr` and does not depend on `LeastMaxValue`. It's the same for all counting semaphores. As Mr. Spock would say: this would not be logical.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik [`std::counting_semaphore<least_max_value>::max() >= least_max_value`](https://wg21.link/thread.sema.cnt#4). On almost all systems, `std::counting_semaphore<1>::max() == 1`. With MSVC's STL, [`std::counting_semaphore<least_max_value>::max() == least_max_value`](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/2f03bdf361f7f153b4216c60a0d9491c0be13a73/stl/inc/semaphore#L61-L63). And with the valid implementation of `std::counting_semaphore<0>` being an empty type, `std::counting_semaphore<0>::max()` would have to be 0.

Comment: Oh, I see, the template can, basically, use `max` to advertise that, as an extra bonus, it can count higher than what's needed.

Comment: Okay, so with microsoft compiler everything is working as described on [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore/counting_semaphore). But for what reason there is no such logic in [GCC](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/semaphore#L46)?